# Issue after migrating from 2.2 to 3.0, default works but can't access area, is there anyway to debug the endpoint resolution?

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrated an asp.net core 2.2 app to 3.0 today, took a bit but everything recompiles and the front (default) works fine, but i can't access the back (separate area). I have my endpoints specified as such (more specific first as the migration documentation recommends) :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("areas", "areas", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

This is the exact configuration i had with UseMVC and endpoints disabled in 2.2

Accessing any url in my area (i only have one) /Back leads to a blank page

There is absolutely nothing of value in the debug output window when running in debug mode with debugger attached :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44355/Back/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 10.9489ms 404
```

I have found a debugger for routes at https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/ but it dates from 2008 so i doubt that would work with endpoint routing.

Is there anything i can do to check what's happening in the endpoint resolution?

Also just to confirm it's not a view problem not a crash in the controller when i manually go to /back/home/index it doesn't ever go in the corresponding function (breakpoint set on first line)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going with a static url start instead of the {area:exists} as i found that in a sample online, this doesn'ts sound like a "clean" fix but it does fix my issue so my solution was to go from

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("areas", "areas", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

To

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("Back", "Back", "back/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Also note sure if it caused the issue or if it was already there but it broke identity ui routing (only that area has authentication so now instead of a blank page i'm redirected to /Identity/... as expected, but that page is now blank)

Comment: Have you tried this with `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areas","{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` instead of `MapAreaControllerRoute`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I haven't but that would be odd ass MapAreaControllerRoute looks like the right tool for the job as i'm registering an area. Sounds like trading a workaround for another workaround

Comment: Am having the same issue, however would disagree that the initial comment is another work around. The above answer works by hard coding the area name (both in pattern and the name parameter itself), The suggestion of @KirkLarkin would be for when you have routes common to all areas.