# Using tag helpers with scaffolded Identity area in Asp.Net Core 3 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-3.0

Porting an older website to Core 3.0 and having some trouble with the new scaffolded Identity area and my anchor tags pointing to pages within that area.

The old MVC code for example

```
<li>
   <a tabindex="-1" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">
      <i class="si si-logout pull-right"></i>Login
   </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a tabindex="-1" asp-controller="Register" asp-action="Register">
     <i class="si si-lock pull-right"></i>Register
  </a>
</li>
```

What does that now become? I'm trying to use asp-area in the tag helper but cant seem to get the action or page paths correct.

```
<li>
    <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">
       <i class="si si-logout pull-right"></i>Login
    </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">
       <i class="si si-lock pull-right"></i>Register
   </a>
</li>
```

And how does one use the asp-action parameter to get to a specific method in the .cs code behind?

Well I created a new Asp.Net Core 3.0 web app, using individual user accounts, scaffolded the Identity and looked at the Login partial, and what I have above is what shows in that template. When I click on register it does nothing but route to a blank screen. 
Using this url

> https://localhost:44367/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FRegister

Now that url doesn't look correct, but that code is how it is in the template.
This is a MVC web application, the scaffolded Identity is Razor. Is this the issue? I would assume that scaffolding puts any libraries required in the solution to render the razor views.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260002/identity-ui-no-longer-works-after-switching-to-net-core-3-endpoint-routing/58260082#58260082

Comment: @Kirk Larkin....sure does, thank you. Now I have to figure out how out of the box, the EmailSender service registration is erring